# VS 2010, Fortran, Find All References, Multi-Project Solution

Tags: visual-studio-2010, fortran, project, solution, find-all-references

I have a multi-project Fortran Solution in VS 2010, using the Visual Fortran Compiler XE 14.0. When I right-click a function and select "Find All References," only references within the given project appear.

I have found similar posts here:

1. [Find all reference on all projects in solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4520206/find-all-reference-on-all-projects-in-solution)
2. [How to find all references in a solution (thus of all projects)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6908485/how-to-find-all-references-in-a-solution-thus-of-all-projects)
3. [Visual Studio 2010 Solution Find all References Not Working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3070878/visual-studio-2010-solution-find-all-references-not-working)

---

Reference (1) is closest to what I would expect (though the fact that any work is involved in achieving this functionality by the end-user is still gut-wrenchingly disappointing). Unfortunately the steps listed seem incongruent with my version of VS 2010 Professional (with SP1); namely, I do not have the option 'Properties>Common Properties' or any mention of 'References'.

Reference (2) has an accepted answer that is simultaneously unintelligible to me and, from what I can understand, seems to suggest that VS 2010 does not provide a simple solution to achieving this functionality.

Reference (3) has a solution that is not applicable to my circumstances.

---

### The Question:

How may I, using VS 2010's built-in options, enable "Find All References" to search all projects in my solution?

(Note: I will not consider an answer that requires me to manually edit some file's text an acceptable answer. I fully expect to find that VS 2010 has a user-friendly way of doing this.)

Comment: Which compiler are you using?

Comment: @Rob Visual Fortran Compiler XE 14.0. Added to question now, thanks.